# No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I want get RSS code from a URL with `Retrofit` and if I enter url staticly in the get annotation everything is OK but with dynamic url I get an error.

My interface service :

```
public interface AllNewsService {
@GET("/fa/rss/{url}")
void getRss( @Path("url") String nGroup ,  Callback<AllNewsRss> callback);}
```

And calling getRss method :

```
DataGetter dg = new DataGetter();
    dg.get().getRss("allnews" ,new Callback<AllNewsRss>() {
        @Override
        public void success(AllNewsRss allNewsRss, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"success");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("*********",error.toString());
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: AllNewsService.getRss: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

**Note:** I added below line to `proguard.cfg` but it didn't work

```
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
```

Comment: You should verify your request code, all retrofit request annotations should be there and well formatted. Check more here: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/no-retrofit-annotation-found-retrofit/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Addition to Destil's answer

Make sure the `parameters` you pass to the `retrofit interface methods(i.e callbacks, headers, body )` are only belongs to `retrofit package`. e.g. Not custom callbacks that you want on your own.

Comment: make sure it belongs to the *right* retrofit package too. In my case I had accidentally imported an annotation from retrofit instead of retrofit2

Answer (score 358):

My problem was that I had the `@POST` annotation, but forgot the `@Body` annotation for the parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with /@Query annotation, since you will get an error: **retrofit.RetrofitError: /@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)**

Comment: god you're a time saver. thanks dude. due to fast development I forgot that annotation too.

Comment: Also an issue with @PUT

Comment: saving lives even years later, cheers ;)

Comment: yeah , here my eyes not gone ..... sometime we forgot small things

Answer (score 23):

Also make sure you add `@Query` or `@Field` for all the parameters , depending on whether you issuing GET/POST.

eg:

```
@GET("/api/Books/GetAll")
void GetRecentBooks(@Query int Offset, Callback<List<Book>> cb);
```

Answer (score 10):

It's way too late, but i just faced the same issue.
I was using retrofit 2.5.0 with 'deferred' and 'await' on my retrofit interface and viewModel. And I read from retrofit github that from 2.6.0 deferred is deprecated and we can switch from deferred to 'suspend'. before i moved my retrofit version up, i just simply changed from deferred to suspend and run it, and got the same error. I solved it by moving my retrofit version from 2.5.0 to 2.6.0.

My point is that maybe there may be a chance that current retrofit version in your app doesn't support the way you use retrofit in your retrofit related classes or interfaces.

Comment: This is it! Updating from 2.5 to 2.6 solved it for me, thanks to you!

Comment: @waseefakhtar no problem :)

Answer (score 9):

My problem was that I am using Kotlin coroutines and used 'suspend' in the Retrofit GET method. Just remove it and everything works fine.

Comment: To be more precise, you should remove "suspend" keyword. Thanks.

Comment: did not work for me an it says could not create adapter!

Comment: I faced the same problem. So how can we use suspend on api service functions?

Answer (score 8):

You need to include @Body if you are doing post

Answer (score 7):

I had the `@Post` annotation but forgot the `@Field` and `@FormUrlEncoded` annotations

Answer (score 5):

(Kotlin) I solved here:

```
//@FormUrlEncoded // Don't used
@POST("orders")
fun saveOrders(@Body orders: Orders): Call<OrdersResponse>
```

Comment: You were getting the error because you forgot to add @ Field annontation to your parameter and used @ FormUrlEncoded

Answer (score 5):

In my case I used Retrofit 2.5.0 instead of the newest version. Update to 2.9.0 and thing went fine again.

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot to initialise adapter first, as mentioned in retrofit api:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
.build();
GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
```

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 2):

Please check the `Path` class you are using and make sure that the package is `retrofit2.http.Path` instead of `org.simpleframework.xml.Path`.
It is a common Retrofit annotation mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Remove from **retrofit interface** all parameters that not belong to this.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you add all dependencies required:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0'
```

Comment: this one resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just forgot to remove Callback parameter for the service call when I start using retrofit 2. Make sure you didn't do the silly mistake I did.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add `@Field("")`

Previously

```
   @POST("/api/verify-phone")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun sendOTP(phone_number: String): Observable<SignInResponse?>
```

Fixed

```
@POST("/api/verify-phone")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun sendOTP(@Field("phone")phone_number: String): Observable<SignInResponse?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I was using suspend functions in the network service interface like so.

```
interface Service {
    @GET("chapters")
    suspend fun fetchChapters() : List<NetworkChapter>
```

I solved it by doing 2 things.
1. Using Gson instead of Moshi library. Remove moshi  converter from retrofit and use Gson converter.
2. Removing coroutine converter factory from retrofit. I think this one was the main problem.

Comment: I am having same problem what do you think main case

Comment: @YodgorbekKomilov I'll need to see your code first before I can advise

Comment: @Gilbert I have fixed issue

Answer (score 1):

Actual problem for me was old **okhttp**. Getting same error even updating retrofit to 2.6.0.

```
okhttp_version = "3.12.1"//remove
okhttp_version = "4.4.0"//works
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use @Post and @body but use multiple options instead a class when I use give object instead of parameters it solves my problems

Answer (score 0):

In my case i forgot to put @HeaderMap in my POST call. It din't have any body, just headers.