# Get response from server with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'd like to get Response from server using retforit.
Here is some code:

```
public class ApiManager {
private static String API_URL = "http://192.168.0.142:8080";
private static ApiService service;

interface ApiService {

    @GET("/login")
    Call<User> auth(Callback<User> cb);
}

private ApiManager() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    service = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}

public void login(String login, String password) {
    service.auth(new Callback<User>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<User> response) {

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                     }
                 }

    );
```

And User class:

public class User {
    private String token;

```
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

}

Server return JSONObject `{"token": "verysecrettoken"}` anyway.

When i call `login` method app was crashed with Exception  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)`

What's wrong? Where i can find retrofit documentation? What is it `Call`?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call enqueue, you have the wrong syntax. Try with this early doc:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: Great article! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same question is asked here: [No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371305/no-retrofit-annotation-found-parameter-1)

Retrofit documentation can be found here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: This question about old version of Retrofit :(
http://square.github.io/retrofit/ at this link only some examples, without good documentation