# How to fix "No Retrofit annotation found." in simple GET callback?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm following a tutorial online to get information from a local API using retrofit2, but when I run my code I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)

I notice most answers online have this problem when POSTing but all I'm trying to do is GET all the items in the database. The API part o this works and when I go to the local IP (10.0.2.2) on the emulator it gives me what I want. I don't understand why I'm getting this problem, actually still trying to fully understand the base code. I also saw some solutions using .enqueue but I guess i don't fully understand how to use it.

```
@GET("/institute/Students")
    void getStudent(Callback<List<Student>> callback);
```

```
 InstituteService serv = restService.getService();
 serv.getStudent(new Callback<List<Student>>() {...}
```

I'm trying to get a list of students from my database but I'm stuck right here. After initiating the Callback it goes straight to the onFailure activity. Any point in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371305/no-retrofit-annotation-found-parameter-1)

Comment: For that one it seems that they wrote a custome Callback but I haven't written any custom Callbacks of my own. So that answer didn't really solve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These interface descriptions should return `Call` instead of `void`:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
...

@GET("institute/students")
Call<ArrayList<Student>> getStudents();
```

Comment: Why should it return ```Call```? I changed to:
```
@GET("/institute/Students")
    Call<List<Student>> getStudent(Callback<List<Student>> callback);
```
But no luck :(

Comment: @KristinVernon it is not what I've wrote; there is no parameter `Callback` (whatever this may be), because it returns a `Call` with `onResponse` and `onFailure` callback.

Comment: Oh I see. But how can I save the response in a ListView? Currently my onResponse takes the response.body() and puts it in a custome adapter for the listview

Comment: just set `ArrayList<Student>`  to an array-adapter. when class `Student` is properly annotated, `response.body()` can be auto-mapped to `ArrayList<Student>`.

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that you are using `callback` not `call` and that too I guess goes as return type not as a parameter.
This interface will return list of students, you can pass query parameters to function if required (eg. StudentId)

```
@GET("institutes/students/") 
Call<List<Student>> getStudentsData();
```

[Please see this article for more information](https://link.medium.com/5QIovZRSLZ)

Comment: Haven't written any custome class for ```Callback```

Comment: Yes (referring to your edit) that was the issue! Thank you so much!